# Is BinData a Mongo ObjectId?

Tags: mongodb

my team is on MongoDB 2.4.10. The id fields look like this

```
{ "_id" : BinData(3,"fEkTlzkZw8m4JJx5nB+fkw==")
```

I know the 3 is the BSON subtype and the value is Base64. But is this an ObjectId or not?  I'm being told it's not. What I need is an ObjectId getTimestamp() method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you see is a *UUID with legacy encoding*.

`BinData(3, ...)`, however, has nothing to do with the [bson types](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#bson-types) as referenced in another answer and as you already pointed out. Of course the bson type is 0x05, since it's binary data. That shows up as `BinData` on the console.

However, `BinData` has, again, an 'internal type', so to speak, the `subtype`. That is the `3` you're seeing as the first parameter to the `BinData` constructor. As you can see [from the spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html), the `subtype` 3 specifies that it is a UUID.

> \x03 UUID (Old) - This used to be the UUID subtype, but was deprecated in favor of \x04. Drivers and tools for languages with a native UUID type should handle \x03 appropriately.

That means this is not just some binary data, but unfortunately, most UUIDs (all?) don't contain a timestamp, so that information is lost I'm afraid.

Note that an `ObjectId` has a different bson type (0x07), that way it is a bit more efficient than `BinData`, because no additional subtype information needs to be stored. **Differently put, `BinData` is never an `ObjectId`** (unless it was explicitly stored as generic binary information, which is counterproductive)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a `ObjectId`, [3](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#bson-types) is for type `Object`

You can simply verify this on Mongo client:

`> var a = { "_id" : BinData(3,"fEkTlzkZw8m4JJx5nB+fkw==")}`

`> a._id instanceof Object`

**true** is returned while on trying

`> a._id instanceof ObjectId`

**false** is returned. For more details [click](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#check-types-in-the-mongo-shell).